# Generic GHC rewrite rules

Tags: haskell, ghc, generic-programming

I recently added an `alterF` function to `Data.Map`, which is a flipped form of `Control.Lens.At.at`.

```
alterF :: (Ord k, Functor f)
       => (Maybe a -> f (Maybe a))
       -> k
       -> Map k a
       -> f (Map k a)
```

`alterF` is designed to be able to offer reasonable performance even for very "heavy" functors like `[]` and even when the keys are fairly expensive to compare. Unfortunately, it's somewhat slower than one might wish in the more common case of a light-weight functor and cheap-to-compare keys.

To patch this up, I've added GHC rewrite rules for the `Const b` and `Identity` functors, rewriting them to simpler implementations that are usually faster. <strike>I'm about to add yet another one, for `(,) b`</strike>. **I added one for `(,) b` and then removed it. See the update below.**

However, I'm a bit annoyed by the fact that I need a specific rule for `(,) b`, because there are many other functors that follow the same pattern. In particular, any time a functor is defined

```
data F b1 b2 ... a = F e1 ... a ... e_n
```

where none of the `e_k` mention `a`, I should be able to rewrite it the same way. Is there some way to do this with GHC `RULES`? Or will I have to wait for some more general rewriting system?

#### Update

Sadly, I realized that my rewrite rule for pairs was invalid (it was too strict), and repairing that made it much less clearly beneficial. So I've scrapped that rule for now. I think the general question remains interesting, however.

Comment: Can you offer more of the code? I'm willing to check out the core if I can get it down to a digestible chunk

Comment: @MichaelKlein, which code are you referring to exactly? It's all in https://github.com/haskell/containers/blob/master/Data/Map/Base.hs except the bitstring implementation in `Data.Utils.BitQueue` in that repo. I suspect the performance problems without rewrite tools are insurmountable, but you're welcome to try.

Comment: I think I might have found a way. `Coercible a b` seems to be the only way to get whether a type is representational/phantom and convert to/from it. I have a somewhat working POC using `coerce`. (I'll be checking the room all occasionally)